# Android Firebase push and get Array List

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a questions how could i push array list to my freebase data base 
and also read it to add a new element , then push it again.

[image]

In the above photo you can see i have added array list **joinedStudents**
and i need to read it and push new elements to it

I've tried the following

```
DatabaseReference requestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    requestsRef.child("requests").child(requestID).child("joinedStudents");


    requestsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String jR = d.getValue(String.class);
                joinedStudents.add(jR);
            }
            joinedStudents.add(studentID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error fetching data from firebase");
        }
    });

    for (String string : joinedStudents) {
        requestsRef.child("requests").child(requestID).child("joinedStudents").setValue(string);
    }
```

but it's not working

Comment: What is the current problem? What is the definition of "but it's not working"?

Comment: This line `requestsRef.child("requests").child(requestID).child("joinedStudents");` does nothing. It builds a reference to a node, but doesn't keep that reference anywhere. You next statement `requestsRef.addValueEventListener(...` simply attaches a listener to the root again, not to the `joinedStudents` node of `requestID`.

Comment: Have you tried what Frank van Puffelen suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have your references slightly mixed up. Try something like:

```
     DatabaseReference joinedStudentsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("requests").child(requestID).child("joinedStudents");


    joinedStudentsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String jR = d.getValue(String.class);
                joinedStudents.add(jR);
            }
            joinedStudents.add(studentID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error fetching data from firebase");
        }
    });

    for (String string : joinedStudents) {
        joinedStudentsRef.child("1").setValue(string); // setValue is for key, value
        // but you have an array
    }
```

Where your reference is now the direct node that you want to monitor/read/write

Comment: i did the the following code , but it seems it has no effect on the database

Comment: add some Log's see what code is being called. Do you see the difference though? You need to listen to the actual nodes you want to know about changes